# como recuperar la carpeta PUBLIC de Filezilla

Tags: filezilla

quisiera saber si alguien sabe como recuperar esa carpeta que sin culpa la borre y ahora no puedo hacer que se vea la pagina en Internet.
para montar la pagina estoy usando filezilla, pero si saben de otro lugar donde la pueda monta y que sea fácil igual me sirve

Comment: Hola hernandez, tal vez no podamos ayudarte, más que con consejos y recomendaciones. Supongo que borraste una carpeta en tu servidor al que te conectas por medio de FTP. Una alternativa sería preguntar con tu proveedor de hosting si tiene un respaldo. Si ya no te interesa recuperarla, busca en Google por un hosting gratuito. 000webhosting es una buena alternativa.

Comment: ok, gracias le preguntare al proveedor si tiene una carpeta de respaldo